# How should I write Elmah-filter for System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, filter, web-config, elmah

I have Elmah-logging on a web service and it is cluttered with one specific error that is irrelevant for me. I want to filter that error out so I can focus on finding my critical errors. I have tried several different syntaxes in web.config but nothing works for me. I can't alter the code writing the errors to the elmah-log, so I have to filter them out in web.config.

The error I want to filter out looks like this in the xml-file:

```
<error errorId="ffc921c0-278a-4191-8c7c-8b9f176bebc7"
       host="MyServer"
       type="System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException"
       message="The given key was not present in the dictionary."
       source="mscorlib"
       detail="System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)&#xD;&#xA;   at MyCompany.ExternWeb.Services.Models.AOListModel.GetLinks(ResultTable searchResult)"
       time="2017-02-01T13:20:54.9789432Z"
/>
```

My elmah-node in web.config with one of my filters I have tried looks like this:

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="D:\LOGS\ELMAH\App_Data" />
    <errorFilter>
        <test>
            <equal binding="Exception.Message" value="The given key was not present in the dictionary." type="string" />
        </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

The filter doesn't work. If I change the "value"-attribute in the filter above to a different string I manage to filter out errors when I try to go to a url that doesn't exist. Those errors look like this:

```
<error errorId="2d885a7b-22db-4754-9d84-02a41aa7f98d"
       application="/LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT"
       host="MyServer"
       type="System.Web.HttpException"
       message="The controller for path '/filter5' was not found or does not implement IController."
       source="System.Web.Mvc"
       detail="System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/filter5' was not found or does not implement IController.&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController&amp; controller, IControllerFactory&amp; factory)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)"
       time="2017-02-01T14:36:09.1374682Z"
       statusCode="404">
    <serverVariables>
        ...
    </serverVariables>
    <cookies>
        ...
    </cookies>
</error>
```

Those errors are filtered out with the below filter:

```
<equal binding="Exception.Message" value="The controller for path '/filter5' was not found or does not implement IController." type="string" />
```

I have also tried to use a regex-filter like:

```
<regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="(.*)" />
```

That works for messages like "The controller for path '/filter5' was not found or does not implement IController." but not for "The given key was not present in the dictionary." **Why can't I filter on the "Message"-attribute, no matter what kind of error? How should write my filter?**

I guess my problem have to do with the System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException-type that I want to filter out. Since it is a collection I have to "dig into" the object in some way to apply my filter on the correct attribute. But how?

Comment: Why can't you alter the code? I have a similar problem with my company's Elmah implementation in that it also generates a bunch of useless "false positive" error logs. I just wrote a little console application which just runs every so often and deletes any files where the message matches a few regex I wrote. Maybe you could do something similar?

Comment: I can't alter the code because I'm not the developer @sab669, and it is a bit too long process to make a new release of the web service. And it is an actual error that I'm intending to find the root cause for but that is of lower priority. So in the meantime I have to filter that error out to be able to find my more critical errors in the elmah-log. We are talking about 1 million errors in one week.

Comment: I could write a powershell-script that deletes the files but I don't want to run that in my production environment. Looping through 1 million files will take some time.